# Error integrating Grafana (community) to Okta

Tags: grafana, openid-connect, okta

I am trying to integrate community edition of Grafana to Okta following this guide - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/okta/

On Okta, I chose OIDC as `web` option which is only available in that mode of app integration. I see the update on the Grafana landing page where it displays `Sign in with Okta` which means the integration is going in the right direction, however, once I click that, I get a `400 Bad Request` with this error.

```
Your request resulted in an error. The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings: *****
```

Where am I going wrong? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

In okta you need to configure a correct redirect URL for the created application. It's whatever Grafana sends in a parameter `redirect_uri` to `/authorize` endpoint of Okta authZ server.

Comment: Thank you! It was also missing `/login/okta` which is why Grafana wasn't visible on the homepage. I had to add `root_url` in the grafana configuration file. Works now.

Any insight on how I can do RBAC?

Comment: what does Grafana documentation say about that? Never dealt with it, but I'd assume that you can assign users to different groups in Okta and Grafana would extract this info to assign privs within itself

Comment: Yeah, I actually am reading through that. So, we are good here. Thank you!

Comment: I have the similar issue, is the only supposed to work with HTTP and not HTTPS? @PhilippGrigoryev

Comment: was your application with http or https? @skp15

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with root_url variable in grafana.ini file